# How to replace blank values and data rearranging by date?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a CSV file containing values for 1988-2020.
The first two columns in the file contain year and month (1988,1 …. 2020,12). The remaining column contains respective values of each date of the month. However, there are missing values for particular dates, and also some months are missing. The missing values need to be replaced by “NA” OR “-99”, and it also needs to consider leap year.
I need to convert this data in the following format without skipping a date from 01-01-1988 to 31-12-2020.

```
Column1,Column2
“dd-mm-yyyy”, “Value”
```

[example data](https://app.box.com/s/38s2qw9ujwcsyeigod29ayamv567drft)

Comment: It looks like you've forgotten to include the code you've done so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I attempted to reshape your data into rows from 01-01-1988 to 31-12-2020 adding missing days filled with `NaN` in every missing month. Could have missed something, so don't hesitate to check it yourself and let me know if something was wrong:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# parse first two columns as dates
df = pd.read_csv('/path_to_file/Data.csv', parse_dates=[[0, 1]], header=None)

# rename columns
df.columns = range(0, 33)

# inspecting the df has shown that the row with index 2016-12-01 is invalid
# and the column 32 is empty  
df = df.drop(columns=32).set_index(0).drop(index='2016-12-01')

# fill missing data in non-month-end days with -99
df.iloc[:, 0:28] = df.iloc[:, 0:28].fillna(value=-99, axis=0)

# reformat index
df.index = df.index.strftime('%m-%Y')

print(df)
```

Intermediate output:

```
           1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10  ...   22  \
0                                                                   ...        
01-1988   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0  ...  0.0   
02-1988   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0  ...  0.0   
03-1988   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0  ...  0.0   
04-1988   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  36.1   0.0   0.0  0.0  ...  0.0   
01-1990   9.8  13.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  16.8  26.0  10.0  0.0  ...  0.0   
...       ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...  ...  ...  ...   
08-2020   0.0   8.0  15.0   9.0   8.0  13.0   0.0  12.0   0.0  0.0  ...  0.0   
09-2020  49.0  15.0   7.0   9.0   5.0  22.0   0.0   0.0   5.0  3.0  ...  0.0   
10-2020   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0  ...  0.0   
11-2020  32.0   4.0  26.0  20.0  10.0   0.0  10.0   0.0   0.0  0.0  ...  0.0   
12-2020   0.0   0.0   3.0   2.0   0.0   8.0   6.0  23.0   3.0  0.0  ...  0.0   

          23    24    25   26    27   28   29   30    31  
0                                                         
01-1988  0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0  
02-1988  0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  NaN   NaN  
03-1988  0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0  
04-1988  0.0  35.3  48.0  0.0   4.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   NaN  
01-1990  0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0  
...      ...   ...   ...  ...   ...  ...  ...  ...   ...  
08-2020  0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  36.0  
09-2020  0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   NaN  
10-2020  0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0  
11-2020  0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0  32.0  2.0  5.0  0.0   NaN  
12-2020  0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0  

[199 rows x 31 columns]
```

```py
# flatten df into 1-d array
flattened = df.to_numpy().flatten()

# expand months in df into days
valid_days = [pd.date_range(start=m, periods=pd.Period(m).days_in_month, freq='D')
              for m in df.index]

# create datetime index by days
valid_days = pd.to_datetime([item for sublist in valid_days 
                             for item in sublist]).strftime('%d-%m-%Y')

# create new DataFrame from flattened values and daily index
df_days = pd.DataFrame(flattened[~np.isnan(flattened)], 
                       index=valid_days, 
                       columns=['value'])

# create the range of all days within the period
total_days = pd.date_range('01-01-1988', '31-12-2020', freq='D').strftime('%d-%m-%Y')

# reindex df_days with all days within the period
df_days = df_days.reindex(total_days)

print(df_days)
```

Output:

```
          value
01-01-1988  0.0
02-01-1988  0.0
03-01-1988  0.0
04-01-1988  0.0
05-01-1988  0.0
    ...     ...
27-12-2020  0.0
28-12-2020  0.0
29-12-2020  0.0
30-12-2020  0.0
31-12-2020  0.0
12054 rows × 1 columns
```

I would be glad to know how to solve this in a much more elegant way.

Comment: flattened = df.to_numpy().flatten()[~np.isnan(flattened)]

NameError: name 'flattened' is not defined . Getting Name Error

Comment: @Bjrj92 fixed in the answer code. Wanted to shorten it all a little after pasting here, but missed that part. The missing values slicing out has been moved to `df_days` instantiation.

Comment: I tried the above code with a different dataset. The following error occurs Length mismatch: Expected axis has 34 elements, new values have 33 elements. [link] https://app.box.com/s/36uazfp5hhm2rl8haufpp33g3u8w3gkp

Comment: Some of the lines in the code were there to fix issues specific to the certain file. There was a blank column in the first file, in the second there wasn't, so you just name columns with `range(0, 32)`. There also may be missing values in month ends that would require filling with `-99`, like missing days `29` not only in February but somewhere else.

Comment: Thank you n.shabankin. After changing the range it works. However following error occurs. "in _check_values_indices_shape_match
    raise ValueError(f"Shape of passed values is {passed}, indices imply {implied}")

ValueError: Shape of passed values is (14368, 1), indices imply (14672, 1)"

Comment: Yes, it would result in an error unless missing values that shouldn't be `NaN` but `-99` are handled. These values are in columns `29:31`. I don't know how to resolve it yet unless manually. I managed to have 14669 of 14703.

Comment: @Bjrj92 alright, apparently these two lines would help for the second file `df.loc[df[28]==-99] = df.loc[df[28]==-99].fillna(value=-99, axis=0)`
`df.loc['02-1993', [30, 31]] = np.nan`